# No Audio from Windows XP after formatting

Tags: windows-xp, audio, troubleshooting, sound-card

I have reinstalled in my Windows XP machine. After it is re-isntalled the audio in my machine has failed.

1. I have installed all the device drivers in my mother board.
2. The Realtek Sound driver is also installed.

Note:
Sound is working when I test the surround settings test in my RealTek program, but unable to play any audio, tried playing both in my local machine and from the internet.

Any clues to troubleshoot?

Comment: some mother boards have problems with Realtek sound cards on Windows XP. search in internet for your mother board model and find some WXP updates o fix it. please, give us the manufacturer and model of your mother board and some info about your sound card, if offboard. use DriverMax software to get info if you do not know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your Realtek configuration application can output audio, then your audio drivers ARE working.

Check the default output device of your system, check your Audio settings in Control Panel (Not the Realtek configuration).

Ensure the Realtek device is set as the output device.

Answer (score 0):

Check your volume setting from your system try or control panel.

if all working fine then try open the window media player and play the default sound file (which is Beethoven's Symphony No. 9 (Scherzo).wma). It might be a problem that your computer not installed the sound codec(or you either playing some other format.